How do I remove non-space trailing character(s) from a string?
Not sure how to remove character (/)

item
100/unit
200/

become

item
100/unit
200


I used LEFT(item, CHARINDEX('/', item)-1) but not working well

What version of SQL Server?

sql 2016 version

select case when item like '%/' then REPLACE ( item , '/' , '' ) else item end

any thing after (/) will keep, anything blank after  (/)  will remove  (/)

Excellent! Thank you

How do i give you credit ( green check)?

@mike this seems like a simple REPLACE. Please add more information if are two or more / present and which one would you like to replace and why ? Will it be replaced with a space or not ? Does / follows always a character or is it any space between ?

If you are on SQL Server 2022+, then you can use RTRIM, as a 2nd parameter to the function (along with LTRIM) was added to denote the character(s) to be trimmed:
SELECT RTRIM(item,'/') AS item
FROM dbo.YourTable;

If you aren't on SQL Server 2022+, then you'll want to REPLACE or TRANSLATE (SQL Server 2017+) the characters with whitespace, and then replace them back. If your value can also contain whitespace, then you'll likely want to replace those first to a character that doesn't appear in the string:
SELECT REPLACE(RTRIM(REPLACE(item,'/',' ')),' ','/') AS item,
       TRANSLATE(RTRIM(TRANSLATE(item,' /','| ')),'| ',' /') AS item
FROM dbo.YourTable;


Since SergeyA hasnt made it an answer, this is another way to do it.
select case when item like '%/' 
then REPLACE ( item , '/' , '' ) 
else item 
end


This would change 100/unit/ to 100unit which probably isn't desired
